# Maintaining Spring flash attribute after redirect is fulfilled

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that sets some flash attributes and calls a redirect. I also have a before controller interceptor in place that will intercept the redirected URL and force another redirection. At this point my Flash attributes are removed as spring thinks that the redirection target has been fulfilled.

I would like to maintain those attributes so that my second controller can have access to them after the second redirect.

Any possible way of achieving that?

Please not that I cannot change the first controller that initially populates them and I need those attributes to reach the second redirection controller.

Comment: Add them to a newly injected `RedirectAttributes` object or put them in the `HttpSession` yourself.

Comment: Let me clarify: Controller A populates RedirectAttributes Object and redirects to controller B. Controller B is never reached and because of the interceptor that will force redirection to controller C. Inside my interceptor I have access to the request, response, and handlermethod. I can only add code to controller C or interceptor. Where do you suggest I retrive them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `HandlerInterceptor`, you should do the following

```
FlashMap lastAttributes = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request); // should hold the attributes from your last request       
FlashMap forNextRequest = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request); // will hold the attributes for your next request
forNextRequest.putAll(lastAttributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is already an accepted answer, but I would like to add some detail to @Sotirios Delimanolis's answer.

What I do is:

```
Map<String, ?> previousFlashAttributes = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
FlashMap flashAttributesForNextRequest = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request);
if (previousFlashAttributes != null && flashAttributesForNextRequest != null) {
    flashAttributesForNextRequest.putAll(previousFlashAttributes);
    RequestContextUtils.getFlashMapManager(request).saveOutputFlashMap(flashAttributesForNextRequest, request, response);
}
```

The last line save the FlashMap into the output.